# style.background with grb

Tags: javascript, colors, styles

```
document.body.style.background = 'blue';
```

I need the above execpt with the ability to change blue to rgba(50, 50, 50, .8);
I looked around and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your browser supports RGBA, it should be straight forward

```
document.body.style.background = 'rgba(50, 50, 50, .8)';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/n2sWF/)

Comment: I didn't have the quotes that's what threw me off

Comment: Problem solved then, when setting styles like this, quotes are generally required.